# Converting a string to an HTML document

Tags: vb.net, string, dom

is there a way to put a string variable into a new declared htmldocument variable without going through a webbrowser ? i tried this

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim v As New WebClient
    Dim page As String = ""
    Dim ahtm As HtmlDocument = Nothing

    page = v.DownloadString("http://www.google.com")
    ahtm.Body.InnerText = page                              'not working
    ahtm.Write(page)                                        'not working neither

End Sub
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean by not working? Is it throwing an exception or simply returning null?

Comment: it's throwing this exception An unhandled exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in WindowsApplication6.exe

Comment: From the docs for [HtmlDocument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.htmldocument%28v=vs.110%29.aspx): "You obtain an instance of HtmlDocument through the Document property of the WebBrowser control." So, no, you can't do it without a WebBrowser control. Note that you don't have to actually display the WebBrowser control. What is the ultimate aim of this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is because you declared ahtm as Nothing. instantiate it and see if it works.

Update:
HtmlDocument is a wrapper around an unmanaged class (IHtmlDocument). Try Declaring a WebBrower and then assigning the ahtm to the web browser document property.

```
WebBrowser wb = new WebBrowser();
HtmlDocument atm = wb.Document;
```

In other words, Web browser is the easiest way.

Update: 
The alternative would be to use something like HtmlAgilityPack. http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/

Comment: when i try to do that, it says "System.Windows.Forms.HtmlDocument' has no constructors"

Comment: as i said i need to do this without going through a webbrowser

Comment: thank you, that actually helped with the htmldocument.loadhtml

Answer (score 3):

**You can use WebBrowser without Navigate().**

```
Public Function CreateDocument(ByVal url As String) As HtmlDocument
      Dim wb As New WebBrowser()
      wb.DocumentText=New WebClient().DownloadString(url)
      Return wb.Document
End Function
```

Comment: In single threaded applications, sure. Otherwise, you're going to get an STA exception.

Answer (score 0):

Try the HTMLAgility Pack.

You can read about it here: http://html-agility-pack.net/

The latest version is available via NuGet.

So you would do something like:

```
Dim aHTML As New HTMLDocument
aHTML.Load(some string variable)
```

Note that you cannot load a URL in this fashion. I'm not sure if you really want to load a URL or if the URL provided was just for reference.

Comment: Could you reference anything specifically related to the question?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to add a reference to `Microsoft.mshtml`.

```
    Private Function GetStatus(ByVal HTMLString As String) As mshtml.HTMLDocumentClass
          Dim htmlDocument As mshtml.IHTMLDocument2 = New mshtml.HTMLDocumentClass()
          htmlDocument.clear()
          htmlDocument.write(HTMLString)
          htmlDocument.close()

          Return htmlDocument
    End Function
```

You very well could try the `HTMLAgility` pack, but that's third party. I feel it's better to attempt using what's built in (unless third party is vastly superior in functionality and/or security). Then you have to worry about licensing and updates. Using `Windows.Forms.WebBrowser` will work too, unless you're multi-threading. I'm sure you could work it out, but it felt too complicated for my needs.